# How to remove index and column to get the desirable result in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have to transpose a dataframe to get the desirable result. I need help.

Example:

df:

```
    filter filter_value      columns user_id   password api_name
0   kol_id       101152       kol_id  vmani4  abede1234      KOL
1  thrc_nm          VIR       jnj_id  vmani4  abede1234      KOL
2   jnj_id      7124166  kol_full_nm  vmani4  abede1234      KOL
3                            thrc_cd  vmani4  abede1234      KOL
```

I filter out two columns from the above dataframe:

df1 = df[['filter', 'filter_value']]

df1:

```
    filter    filter_value      
0   kol_id       101152       
1   thrc_nm      VIR       
2   jnj_id       7124166  
3
```

After transpose I am getting below dataframe:

```
                   0        1        2 3
filter        kol_id  thrc_nm   jnj_id
filter_value  101152      VIR  7124166
```

but i want to Remove the index label and column label both.

df_final:

```
kol_id    thrc_nm     jnj_id
101152    VIR         7124166
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas Transpose will do what you need. Assuming the below is in a dataframe: df

```
filter      filter_value
0   kol_id       101152
1  thrc_nm          VIR
2   jnj_id      7124166

df = df.transpose().reset_index(drop=True)

print(df.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

Output:

```
kol_id  thrc_nm   jnj_id
 101152      VIR  7124166
```

EDIT: updated based on comment from O/P

Comment: How to remove index label and column label both after transpose?

Comment: Please check my desirable output.

Comment: @ashmita I have updated to capture this - This gives you the output needed as a DataFrame

Comment: Remove the column - 0 1 2 3 as well

Comment: They are there as an attribute of the DataFrame. You need to convert to a string to get what you are asking about. Edited answer based on this.